# Rails generic form for with Braintree form builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, braintree

I have a similar form like this:

```
    <%= form_for :customer,
  :params => @result && @result.params[:customer],
       :errors => @result && @result.errors.for(:customer),
       :builder => BraintreeHelper::BraintreeFormBuilder,
       :url => Braintree::TransparentRedirect.url,
       :html => { :autocomplete => "off"} do |f| -%>
      First name: <%= f.text_field :first_name , :value => "John"%><br />
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

When I try to add the value to that text field is not letting me. However, if I take the builder from the form_for tag, I am able to do so. Anyone has had experience with Braintree form builder?

Answer (score 1):

Siwei Shen is on the right track...

Form builders in Rails help you tie your forms to models in your application and generate values, names, and IDs for your form elements that correspond to model attributes. They're tremendously helpful, but sometimes it's necessary to override what they give you.

The example form builder you found in the Braintree Rails example app provides some things that are helpful since TR forms post directly to our gateway rather than your app and gives your form fields attribute names and default values that Braintree's gateway will expect as well as helps to populate validation errors which are returned to your app.

In this particular case, the form builder is ultimately merging the values for the inputs (including :first_name) with either the existing value (if any) or nil (over-writing what you've passed in.

https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby_examples/blob/master/rails_tr_checkout/app/helpers/braintree_form_builder.rb#L22

Feel free to modify the form builder to suit your needs!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. How would I override that from my app though?

Answer (score 0):

when using "form_for", the default value is the form-object's value.  e.g.

```
@person = Person.new(:first_name => "Jack")

<%= form_for :person do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>  
<% end %>
```

and you will get a text input with the default value "Jack" :

```
<input type="text" value="Jack"/>
```

so, when using `f.text_field`, you are not able to set the default value, unless you change the form-object ( here is the @person).

If you want to set the default value, I suggest you either use "form_tag", which does not have "form object", or use jQuery to implement the default value stuff.

Comment: I am not using any kind of @person object in my controller....I am populating my form into another service. I have updated my question.. Sorry for confusion

Comment: then use `form_tag`, not `form_for`.

Comment: I can use form_for for generic kinds. Look at generic form for here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for